# Firebase Cloud Messaging notification per OS type (iOS/Android/Web) usage

Tags: android, ios, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are implementing FCM in our iOS, Android and web apps and saw that the documentation speaks about sending different values to different OS types via ApnsConfig, WebpushConfig and AndroidConfig objects  (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages)

We tried all kinds of variations but we just can't get this to work. Does anybody know what we are doing wrong? Here is a example of how we try to send something:

```
{
    "notification" : {
        "title" :"Title",
        "body": "Body",
    }
    "data" : {
        "all_devices_key" : "all_devices_value",
    }
    "content_available": true,
    "to": "...",
    "apns": {
      "headers": {
        "ios_only_key": "ios_only_value",
      },
    }
}
```

We also tried the payload and other combinations in the apns like the following but nothing ever comes through.

```
"apns": {
  "payload": {
    "ios_only_key": "ios_only_value",
    "aps" : {
    "alert" : {
            "title" : "Game Request",
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
            "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
        },
        "badge" : 5
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
  },
}
```

Are we misunderstanding the documentation? How can we send specific key-value-pairs to only iOS or Android or Web?

Comment: The documentation you linked for `Message` describes required field "target" which can be one of `token`, `topic` or `condition`.  You don't show a target field in your posted messages.  Do you have one?

Comment: [This documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_post_request) shows an example of sending a simple v1 message.  Have you tried a basic case like this to confirm that your URL and authorization are correct?

Comment: Yeah, v1 is working just fine. However, we need different messages/ formats/arguments for web and mobile apps.

Comment: Can you post the response body you get (with private fields redacted) when you post a send request?

Comment: You could also try sending the example message in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/11/whats-new-with-fcm-customizing-messages.html) to see if it works.